# How to use base class variable using a different name in inheriting class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to create an abstract class for ordinary differential equations, and have its independent variable use a different name in the inheriting classes. How do I go about that?

I don't want to allocate more memory for the renaming of the variable, i.e. create a new variable or a pointer to the base variable, as that's counterproductive. I just want to be able to access it with a different name in my inheriting classes, so that it's easier to know what the independent variable represents.

Mayhap a better question is, does the functionality of variable name overriding even exist in C++?

To give some code:

```
class ODE {
private:
    int numEqns
    double* q; // dependent variables
public:
    double s; // independent variable
    
    ODE(int numEqns) {
        this->numEqns = numEqns;
        this->q = new double[numEqns];
    }
    SetQOfIdxTo(int idx, double val) {
        this->q[idx] = val;
    }
};
```

```
class SpringODE : public ODE {
public:
    double mass;
    double c;   // damping coefficient
    double k;   // spring constant
    double d0;  // initial deflection
    SpringODE(double mass, double c, double k, double d0) : ODE(2) {
        this->mass = mass;
        this->c = c;
        this->k = k;
        this->d0 = d0;
        time = 0.0;
        SetQOfIdxTo(0, 0.0);
        SetQOfIdxTo(1, d0);
    }
};
```

The code is based on the one given in Grant Palmer's book "Physics for Game Programmers". The book in question being why I'm asking this question, as out of nowhere the time variable's Get function returns the base classes' GetS() function, which just returns "s" (albeit the code in the book is written in Java).

Comment: Perhaps the abstract class shouldn't have any member variables at all? _"does the functionality of variable name overriding even exist in C++"_ no, but you can access it using functions with whatever name you want.

Comment: `auto& my_new_name = old_name;`?

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: This would break the principle of least astonishment for me. Seems an awkward choice and if the name shouldn't be the same then you're probably not modeling an is-a type relationship of inheritance.

Comment: Perhaps a little example would be in place?

Comment: `auto& my_new_name() { return old_name; }`?

Comment: Why not let the name be provided by the user when defining the equation?

Comment: Alright, I've updated my question to include relevant code.

Comment: Why not just remove `double* q;` and `int numEqns` from the base? Is the base class ever used on its own? If you really need those in the base, why not `std::vector<double> q;` instead? You initialize the base class with `ODE(2)`. What are those two `double`s used for in the base?

Comment: The initialization with 2 for the base class is because there are two coupled first-order ODEs.
Reason I use `double* q;` instead of `std::vector<double> q;` is partially because I forgot vectors existed, and partially because I'm using the book code as a reference guide, wherein they use `double q[];`. Besides, I don't need all the various functionalities that comes with a vector.

Comment: Since you are learning C++ from a java book, I would say that you _do_ need the various functionalities that comes with a `std::vector`. Memory management with raw owning pointers is going to bite hard if you are not used to it. `new` in C++ takes a lot more care than `new` in java.

Comment: Right, gotta do a ton of delete calls if I use new everywhere, and in some cases it'll be very tricky to figure out how to delete a created array. Fair enough, I'm switching to std::vector for the arrays. Thanks for that warning, so that I didn't have to waste time on trying to figure out why I was getting issues later on.

Comment: I'm learning Spanish from a Russian book called Учить испанский.  It has been very difficult and slow going, since I don't know Russian.